# How does Paypal validate the transaction amount?

Tags: tampering, paypal

How does Paypal validate the transaction amount if the buyer changed the purchase amount using http parameter tampering attack?

Comment: Server can create a session that binded to price and verify it after form submit.

Answer (score 2):

> How does Paypal validate the transaction amount?

I don't think they do, most of the time. It used to be that Google Checkout required signed shopping carts by default, which would certainly prevent tampering but require non-trivial server-side programming. I expect this feature was disabled by at least 90% of web developers interfacing with Google Checkout.

There isn't a real need to validate before placing the order. The seller can simply check the amounts at the fulfillment side of the order. It's less code to do it that way, and there isn't a real need to prevent someone from paying the wrong amount on purpose -- you just don't serve them with whatever you were selling and then act all confused when they ask for their money back to get on their nerves as much as possible. This is based on personal experience running multiple sites that accept payment through PayPal.